# Email Deleted Without Being Read

Tags: exchange-2007

We have some automated software that checks certain Exchange 2007 mailboxes via POP3.  When a customer's incoming e-mail requests a read receipt, Exchange seems to be sending back a non-read receipt.

```
Not read: <subject> 
Your message was deleted without being read on...
```

The order in which the software issues POP3 commands is

```
USER 
PASS 
STAT 
UIDL 
TOP # 0 
LIST # 
RETR # 
TOP # 0 
RSET 
DELE # 
QUIT
```

Our exchange administrator has been able to duplicate this issue via raw POP3 commands over telnet, port 110.  The commands he ran were simply

```
USER 
PASS 
STAT 
RETR # 
DELE # 
QUIT
```

Does Exchange 2007 translate POP3 commands to read flags?  If so, it should tell that I've issued a RETR command to retrieve the message.  Is this a bug?  Is there a way to disable the sending of read receipts for specific mailboxes or globally?

Comment: I prefer to become violent with people who use the "Read Receipts". That seems to work for me. (It'd be nice to be able to disable the feature organization-wide in Exchange. Perhaps even administer electrical shocks to the people who try to use it thru their mice...)

Comment: Funny, but shocking our customers might shock our bottom line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be an interesting problem.  I found a few links to ansewrs, but it looks like this one is the best of the bunch. [MSexChange](http://forums.msexchange.org/Disable_Read_reports_ouside_the_organization_(internet)%25_read_receipts/m_1800450544/tm.htm)

Synopsis...

a sure fire way of ensuring read receipts are not sent to external people is to configure FOUR transport rules...
Rule 1:
From users outside the organization
Remove header "X-Confirm-Reading-To"
Rule 2:
From users outside the organization
Remove header "Disposition-Notification-To"
Rule 3:
From users outside the organization
Remove header "Return-Receipt-To"
Rule 4:
From users outside the organization
Remove header "Receipt-Requested-To"

Comment: This works exactly as I hoped it would.